Issue in Converting HTML Output to Table
I need to scrape data from this link: https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/15396850/embed?auto=1
This is my Python code:
import pandas as pd
import html.parser
import requests
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver

base_url = "https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/15396850/embed?auto=1"


class MyParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, html):
        self.matches = []
        self.match_count = 0
        super().__init__()        

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.matches.append(data)
        self.match_count += 1

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag == "div":
            if attrs.get("fl-layout-primary-container"):
                self.handle_data()
        else: return
        
url = base_url.format(page_number)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source

parser = MyParser(html)
parser.feed(html)

for item in parser.matches:
    print(item)

The output I get has the metadata for the table. I have not been able to figure out how to convert that into a csv table.
This is what my output looks like.

The data you're looking for is embedded as Json inside the HTML page. To get them to pandas dataframe, save it as CSV you can use next example:
import json
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/15396850/embed?auto=1"
html_source = requests.get(url).text

column_names = json.loads(
    re.search(r"_Flourish_data_column_names = (.*})", html_source).group(1)
)
data = json.loads(re.search(r"_Flourish_data = (.*})", html_source).group(1))

all_data = []
for r in data["rows"]:
    all_data.append(r["columns"])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=column_names["rows"]["columns"])
print(df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False))

Saves data.csv (screenshot from LibreOffice):


I have a related question, which might be stupid. I understand you got "_Flourish_data_column_names" by looking at the page source. Can I do the same for visualization pages like these: https://flo.uri.sh/story/891697/embed?auto=1#slide-0? I read the page source and could find where the data lies. But I couldn't get the same var names like you did for the previous link.
